# Flutter TextField with custom node is hiding keyboard on first focus

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hello I have a TextField that is required to be not focused on the first render, I have solved it by settings autofocus property to false and wrapping the whole page with **GestureDetector** with

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
textfieldController.clear();
```

and achieved it but I'm having a little bit of a problem when I click text field the first time it hides the keyboard and stays focused, after clicking the second time it works as I expected. The expected result would be textfield starts unfocused and when I click it the keyboard should come out.

[image: Current behavior]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way..

```
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => constants.dismissKeyboard(context),
      child: Scaffold(
       .....
      ),
    );
```

/////

```
void dismissKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  }
```